# Monthly credit card payment calculator shows Syntax Error

Tags: python, syntax-error, banking

This program is supposed to calculate the credit card balance after one year if a person only pays the minimum monthly payment required by the credit card company. When I try to run it, it shows a SyntaxError, and I'm not sure why. Here's my code:

```
def ccb(balance, annualInterestRate, monthlyPaymentRate):
    monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
    month = 0
    for calc in range(12):
        minMonthlyPaymentRate = balance * monthlyPaymentRate
        unpaidBalance = balance - minMonthlyPaymentRate
        interest = monthlyInterestRate * unpaidBalance
        print ("Month | Balance | Unpaid Balance | Interest")
        print (month + " | " + round(balance) + " | " + round(unpaidBalance) + " | " + Interest)
        balance = unpaidBalance + Interest
        month += 1 
    print ("Remaining balance: " + round(balance))
```

Comment: Show the full error message...

Comment: There is no syntax error in that code. Either this is not your actual code, or the error you're getting is not a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

A few things (though none appear to throw SyntaxError - seconding Andrew in the comments, if it's a SyntaxError - share the full message):

1) You can't implicitly make an integer a string, you need to cast it. Ex:

```
str(round(balance))
```

instead of

```
round(balance)
```

2) 'Interest' is never defined, but 'interest' is.

With those fixed, it runs fine.

Also, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) might be relevant ;)